# CI Session not working on MAMP & XAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to run the CI project on MAMP but the session variable didn't work. What configuration should I make?

Comment: show us what did you do (code, autoloads, config, controller, etc)

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of your cookie path? Logs output will help here

Comment: Same project code is running on windows environment without any error.

Comment: Did you set your session save path something like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';` folder permission 0700

Comment: Make sure you have named the filenames and classes on, controller, models etc where **ONLY** the first letter is upper case the rest lower case explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score -2):

try loading the codeigniter session library in your controller or in

`config->autoload->library = (array('session'));`

Comment: The same project is working on another environment without any error, so it has probably somehing to do with folder permissions.

Comment: set all folder permission to 777 if you have any doubt .